# set :linked_files and set :linked_files for uploads in capistrano3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to upload my files and folder to my server using capistrano3.
I want that folder to be shared amongst all the releases. For example I have a folder named media and it contains sub directories and files. I want that to be placed under shared directory created by Capistrano 3.
I have seen this

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

Is there any way where I can upload all the files and subdirectories of media into shared directory.

Note :Basically I want my uploads to be untouched from capistrano3. Is there any way where I will just create the structure of the uploads folder and it will remain intact from my capistrano deploys.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `media` dir into `linked_dirs`, if you want that folder to be shared amongst all the releases.

`set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system media}`

Then write a task like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'upload media files'
  task :upload_media_files do
    remote_path, local_path = "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/shared/media", '/your/local/media/path'
    on release_roles :app do
      upload!(local_path, remote_path, recursive: true)
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:check', 'deploy:upload_media_files'
```

It's a `scp` command. According to the [source code](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp/blob/master/lib/net/scp.rb#L331), the command would be: `scp -t -r /remote/shared/media`.

If you don't want overwrite the existing files, you should use `rsync`

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'upload media files'
  task :upload_media_files do
    remote_path, local_path = "#{fetch(:deploy_to)}/shared", '/your/local/media/path'
    on release_roles :app do |server|
      system("rsync -avzr #{local_path} #{fetch(:deployer)}@#{server.hostname}:#{remote_path}")
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:check', 'deploy:upload_media_files'
```

Comment: will the upload works like rsync because I don't want to overwrite the files/directories on freshrelease